# how to use pivot on stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server

I was used pivot by  dynamic sql code. It was successful. But when I was create stored procedure but not display result 
code is

```
create procedure GradeDisplayByList 
@semester nvarchar(200),
    @StartRoll int,
    @EndRoll int
as begin
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Subject) 
                    from  mrkdetail where Semester=@semester and RollNo>=@StartRoll and RollNo<=@EndRoll 

                     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT RollNo,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              SELECT 
               RollNo, Subject,Grade
                            FROM mrkdetail where  Semester=''+@semester+'' and RollNo>='''+convert(varchar(200),@StartRoll,111)+''' and RollNo<='''+convert(varchar(200),@EndRoll)+'''

            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                Max(Grade)
                for Subject  in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
execute sp_executesql @query
end
```

Please help

Comment: use print @query before execute.Then pass value in sp,run it like this exec GradeDisplayByList 'semestervalue',@startroll,@endroll.this will print the query along with value.you can copy back that printed query and execute again to check where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

This part where you determine `@cols` could be modified to this:

```
select @cols = STUFF(
(SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Subject) 
from  mrkdetail 
where Semester=@semester and RollNo>=@StartRoll and RollNo<=@EndRoll 
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
```

And also change this:

```
Semester=''+@semester+'' and RollNo>='''+convert(varchar(200),@StartRoll,111)+''' and RollNo<='''+convert(varchar(200),@EndRoll)+'''
```

to this:

```
Semester='''+@semester+''' and RollNo>='+convert(varchar(200),@StartRoll)+' and RollNo<='+convert(varchar(200),@EndRoll)+'
```

Comment: My pleasure! If it helps feel free to upvote/accept it. :)